# List in Ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I have Ansible Playbook which i want to use as Generic Playbook(choronically same for all).
Is there is any possible way to create List in inside vars: section and iterate it inside PlayBook? So that i just go and edit my vars section or var.yml file

PFB the part of my desired playbook

```
- name: Test playbook 
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root

  vars:
    list_dict3: 
      -  packages: [ 'python-setuptools','python-dev','libfuzzy-dev','libffi-dev','screen']

  tasks:
    - name: Accessing list of dictionary
      apt: pkg={{item.packages}} state=present
      with_items: list_dict3
```

Comment: You should be more specific. What is *list* here? What is *dict* here? What is *list of dictionary* here? No sure what you really want.

Comment: The Variable 
packages: [ 'python-setuptools','python-dev','libfuzzy-dev','libffi-dev','screen']

is list (like lists in python), Apology about confusing dict3 word it shouldn't have impact 

What i want is a variable which contains list of applications and iterate through it inside in apt module.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you really want, because your variable structure is very strange, but to make your `apt` task correct, you should write:

```
- name: Accessing list of dictionary
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ list_dict3[0].packages }}"
```

Comment: i mean it should run the loop with_items and iterate over "packages" list

like in python

packages = [ 'python-setuptools','python-dev','libfuzzy-dev','libffi-dev','screen']

for pkg in packages:
    os.system('apt-get install {}'.format(pkg))